# How to view Process Builder as Visual Flow

Tags: process-builder

To view a process builder flow as a visual flow try and delete an element used by that Process builder flow (ie an object field etc).  The delete will not be allowed and say its cause its used in a flow and will provide a link. 
Click on the link and you will be taken to the Visual Flow screens but be looking at a Process Builder flow which can be opened like a V-flow.

Answer (score 1):

For me it is working fine. The flow should be an autolaunched flow and also there should be some connecting element. Only one element in the flow will not work.

Comment: I am not having a problem with PB, just noting a quirk in it. If the PB calls an auto-launched flow & you try & delete that auto-launched flow, you get the same result.  A link to the PB flow that lets you see it as a Visual flow.